# PHP update create duplicate records

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Why when I update a record it does it but creates about 15 duplicate records in the table?
My code is below.
Any help would be great

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","root","","assignment2");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$module_id=$_POST['module_id']; 
$user_id=$_POST['user_id']; 
$grade=$_POST['grade']; 


mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE grades SET module_id='$module_id', user_id='$user_id',
grade='$grade' WHERE module_id='$module_id'");              
mysqli_close($con);
echo "Student successfully updated!"

?>
```

Comment: Is `module_id` a unique identifier? If not, any record with that ID will get updated

Comment: Yeah it is. For example I have module_id, user_id and grade.

If I put module_id as 1, user_id as 1 and grade as say 99

then try and edit the grade later to say 77, it will but it'll give 15 records of 1, 1, 77

Comment: First off, `module_id` should be the primary key with AI turned on and hence a unique identifier. Then to fulfill all righteousness, add `LIMIT 1` to your query

Comment: module ID is a foreign key, it's already linked to the module table as a primary key. These fields I'm editing are in the grades table...

Comment: The LIMIT1 seems to have worked!

Comment: The LIMIT1 did seem to have worked but now it's adding another record rather than changing the orginal

Comment: If `module_id = '$module_id'` then why on earth are you setting `module_id = '$module_id'` as well??

Comment: @dpotts take the `module = '$module_id'` part out of your SET fields - it seems like you're changing it every time, and using it to identify it as well. LIMIT 1 is literally just limiting the damage you're doing to your database to one record at a time, you need to fix the cause of the problem to stop it happening completely.